# Merged column headers in jasper report

Tags: dynamic, header, jasper-reports, report, dynamic-jasper

I am using Dynamic jasper for one of my projects and I need to generate some reports that contain merged column headers.

Something like this

(the average height|weight part of it)

```
/-----------------------------------------\
|          |      Average      |   Red    |
|          |-------------------|  eyes    |
|          |  height |  weight |          |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  Males   | 1.9     | 0.003   |   40%    |
|-----------------------------------------|
| Females  | 1.7     | 0.002   |   43%    |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

It seems like a very simple thing to do but, I have looked all over the internet and couldn't find a solution. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the version of dynamic jasper I was using did not support colspan.Fortunately  this feature has been added to the latest version.

Check out this link for help:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230606122914/http://dynamicjasper.com/2011/12/27/how-to-create-colspan-headers/